# Search from with select option for which domain

Tags: forms

I have a mediawiki multi language site (on sub domains) and I am trying to set up a start page similar to wikipedia, where a user can enter a search term, and then select their language from a select list.

I have no idea where to start, not much experience building forms, So with this question I am at least looking for clues and directions to go.

My idea is a simple search form, and depending on which language was selected, when a user submits, it goes to the url (related to the select list), and appends the searched term.

Answer (score 0):

A simple form to get you started (the form allows you to input an URL and select a language)

```js
function myFunction() {
  // get input form values
  var url = document.getElementById("iUrl").value;
  var langEl = document.getElementById("iLang");
  var iLang = langEl[langEl.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log("URL = ", url);
  console.log("Lang = ", iLang);
  window.open(url + "&lr=" + iLang);
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="javascript:myFunction();">
  <input size="35" type="text" id="iUrl" name="text" value="https://www.google.com/search?as_q=" />
  <br>
  <select name="language" id="iLang">
    <option value="lang_en">EN</option>
    <option value="lang_es">ES</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```